# tensorly.kruskal_to_tensor() method explanation

Tags: python, tensorly

I'm trying to understand tl.kruskal_to_tensor () method in tensorly package. 
In the [webpage](http://tensorly.org/stable/modules/generated/tensorly.kruskal_tensor.kruskal_to_tensor.html) I understand that it takes as input a list of matrices and produces the  tensor whose cp-decomposiiton are the matrices? It takes as input a list of matrices.

But I saw the following code:

```
import tensorly as tl
rank =5
dim1= 9
dim2=8
dim3=7
A= tl.tensor(np.random.normal(0,1,[dim1,rank]))
B= tl.tensor(np.random.normal(0,1,[dim2,rank]))
C= tl.tensor(np.random.normal(0,1,[dim3,rank]))

T_approx_old = tl.kruskal_to_tensor((np.ones(rank),[A,B,C]))
```

I don't understand the np.ones(rank) argument in the method.

What does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of `kruskal_to_tensor` is documented in the [dev version of the API](http://tensorly.org/dev/modules/generated/tensorly.kruskal_tensor.kruskal_to_tensor.html).

The `np.ones` corresponds to the weight of the Kruskal tensor: a Kruskal tensor expresses a tensor as a weighted sum of rank one tensors (outer product of vectors, collected as the columns of the factor matrices). In your case, the weights of the sum are all ones and accumulated in this vector of ones.

Note that you could [normalize](https://github.com/tensorly/tensorly/blob/fb9a6eeef5402daf70089aedc82d5a45f00ac143/tensorly/kruskal_tensor.py#L104) the factors of your Kruskal tensor and absorb their magnitude in theses weights.